# Is there a way to make a textContent stay permanent?

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

Sorry if it's a dumb question, currently making a tic tac toe game, I made the user able to click the board which are buttons. When clicked upon, it will place the players marker("X" or "O").

**Problem: Once a player has pressed it, I do not want that textContent to change at all. Is there a way to achieve that result?**

```
const playRound = (e) => {
    let playerInput = e.currentTarget.dataset.number
    placeMarker(playerInput, getActivePlayer().marker);
    e.currentTarget.textContent = getActivePlayer().marker;
    _switchPlayerTurn();

    printNewRound();
    console.log(`${board}`);
    console.log(typeof board);
    console.log(GameBoard.getBoard());
}

//Event Listener
const ScreenController = (function ScreenController() {
  const {
    playRound
  } = Game;
  const board = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
  board.forEach(element => {
    element.addEventListener('click', playRound);
  })
})();
```

Codepen:https://codepen.io/jimmyjimenez2400/pen/ZEjvrPq

I did try to look up of how I can make it stay permanent with no luck.

I did try to use innerHTML but knowing it can cause issues for security. I just avoid it.

Feeling that I probably have to make an if statement, where "If textContent changed, then somehow lock it". I'm expecting the textContent to not change on second click on the element.

Comment: Maybe try to keep track of the squares that are already clicked and conditionally alter textcontent with marker. There is no "locking" mechanism on div itself

Comment: You may check if the textContent is a number. If the textContent is a number, then update the textContent, else do nothing.

Comment: @SurajRao 
You're right I could do that as well. I'm going to try both methods and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @TheKNVB Okay, I see. So I have to check if the textContent is a number since I'm targeting the dataset-number, then update the textContent, else do nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think setting the `once` option to `true` is the most concise:

```
element.addEventListener('click', playRound, { once: true });
```

Although it is not supported by IE: https://caniuse.com/once-event-listener

docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#parameters

---

Example:

```js
let count = 0;

const playRound = (e) => {
  const letter = count++ % 2 == 0 ? "O" : "X";
  e.target.textContent = letter;
  console.log(`Turn ${count} complete`); 
}

const board = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
board.forEach(element => {
  element.addEventListener('click', playRound, { once: true });
})
```

```css
.row {
display: flex
}

.square {
display: flex;
cursor: pointer;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border: 1px solid black;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

div.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 66px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
```

---

As suggested in the comments, here is a slightly less concise method that supports IE. It does the exact same thing as above, removes the event listener at the end of the callback function.

```js
let count = 0;

const playRound = (e) => {
  const letter = count++ % 2 == 0 ? "O" : "X";
  e.target.textContent = letter;
  console.log(`Turn ${count} complete`); 
}

const board = document.querySelectorAll('.square');
board.forEach(element => {
  const callback = (e) => {
    playRound(e);
    element.removeEventListener('click', callback);
  }
  element.addEventListener('click', callback);
})
```

```css
.row {
display: flex
}

.square {
display: flex;
cursor: pointer;
width: 40px;
height: 40px;
border: 1px solid black;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}

div.as-console-wrapper {
max-height: 66px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
<div class="row">
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
<span class="square"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer, if you want to support I.E. just use the same strategy but remove the element listener inside the function after the element is clicked with element.removeEventListener

Comment: @ChrisHamilton
 So this works similar as in the first example you've shown, the only difference is that the first uses `once: true`. The latter is essentially the same thing as `once: true`, but is more compatible throughout browsers.

Okay, I'm going to use your latter, thank you for this! I'm learning a lot.

Comment: Thank you @Chris! I wish I can upvote but I'm missing 4 reputation

Comment: @Jim2400 Internet Explorer is essentially a dead browser, I wouldn't jump through hoops trying to support it unless you have some specific reason to do so. `once` is supported by every other browser, as you can see in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add an if clause right at the beginning of your event listener function, like

```
const playRound = (e) => {
  if (e.currentTarget.textContent) return;
  ...
}
```

This will effectively "lock" any already filled out cell. An empty cell will have a `.textContent` of `""` which in JavaScript will be seen as falsy.

Ok, if the initial content is numeric, then you should of course check differently, like:

```
if ("XO".includes(e.currentTarget.textContent)) return;
```

Comment: Initially the divs contain numbers. This will prevent any player from marking the div

Comment: Ah I see. So the if/else statement was the right approach for this. Thank you so much @Carsten!

Comment: A rejecting  `if` statement is quite enough, no `else` is needed.

Comment: @Carsten, Okay I'm going to try it out right now and let you know what happens from there.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann Thank you! It actually did work. I had to look up what ".includes" does in the documentation, thanks for teaching me something new.